# Why my execution plan is the same with index and without and sometimes has missing index?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, indexing, geospatial, spatial-index

I tested my procedure with and without index to compare the result. My problem is I dont know why my spatial index in noy in the execution plan when I test but sometimes in the execution plan there is a misssing index; I dont know why I have this, can someone help with this? My procedure looks like:

```
create procedure    [dbo].[p_search_vehicle]
@IdCustomer int,
 @idGroupVehicle int = null,
 @ResultCount int= null,
 @Radiant int= null 
 as
 begin
 if @IdCustomer is null
    begin
        print 'The argument cannot be null'
        return 
    end
 declare @start geography
 SET @start = (select location from Customer where idCustomer=@idCustomer )
 ---@Result null group null radiant null
    if @ResultCount is null and @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@Result null  radiant null
            else if @ResultCount is null and @Radiant is null
    select  top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@Radiant null  
            else if @Radiant is null
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
             ---@@idGroupVehicle  null @Radiant is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @Radiant is null
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            ---@idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null and @ResultCount is null
    select top 10 idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
        --- @idGroupVehicle is null 
            else if  @idGroupVehicle is null 
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            --- @Result is null 
            else if  @ResultCount is null 
    select TOP(10) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000   <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
            --- all options
    else
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
 end
GO
```

this procedure retunr list of vehicle which is the nearest to user
i have a spatial index for table vehicle is that

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SIndx_Vehicle_locationVehicle] ON [dbo].[Vehicle]
(
    [locationVehicle]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID 
WITH (
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 12, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I test this procedure with `set statistics io on` I don't see my spatial index in the execution plan. I dont know why but I have a green message with missing index.

Can someone explain why I have the same execution plan with index and without?

[image]

Comment: Possibly to do with the `/1000` on each reference. Have a read through the _Geometry Methods Supported by Spatial Indexes_ at [Spatial Indexes Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to see the supported predicate forms.

Comment: i read this doc